# Coloring every point by a real value in a ggplot2/ggpairs plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have three variables `a`, `b`, `c`. I want to make a `ggpairs` plot of `a` and `b` with each variable (in all of the panels) colored by `c`. How can I do this?

## Code example

```
library(ggplot2)
library(GGally)
N <- 100
a <- rnorm(N, 0, 1)
b <- rnorm(N, 0, 1)
point.colors <- runif(N, 0, 1)
ggpairs(data=data.frame(a, b)) # How to add point.colors here?
```

---

I can do this using base R pretty easily:

```
plot(a, b, col=colorRampPalette(c('red', 'blue'))(N)[1+floor(N*point.colors)])
```

How to do it with `ggpairs`?

(edit: off-by-one)

Comment: `ggpairs(data=data.frame(a, b, c=colorRampPalette(c('red', 'blue'))(N)[floor(N*point.colors)]), columns=1:2, color="c")`?

Comment: Doesn't work for me either.

Comment: (accidentally deleted) `Error in data.frame(a, b, c = colorRampPalette(c("red", "blue"))(N)[floor(N *  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 100, 99`

Comment: but that seems to be because `length(colorRampPalette(c('red', 'blue'))(N)[floor(N*point.colors)])` is `N-1` for some bizarro reason

Comment: ah, it worked!!! have to add 1 to the floor command, otherwise some random instantiations will make it fail.

Comment: ok, next issue, now there's `N` histograms, one for each color; how do I make it only plot the original black one?

Comment: Why not change the plot within the ggpairs object?

    `p = ggpairs(data = data.frame(a,b))`
    `p21 = qplot(a,b,colour = point.colors)`
    `p[2,1] = p21`

Comment: @bouncyball `Error in p[2, 1] = p21 : incorrect number of subscripts on matrix`

Comment: but it works if I change `p$plots[[3]]` to `p21`

Comment: @bouncyball I'm satisfied. Submit and I will accept

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not change the plot within the ggpairs object?

```
p = ggpairs(data = data.frame(a,b)) 
p21 = qplot(a,b,colour = point.colors) 
#next line didn't work for user
#p[2,1] = p21
p$plots[[3]] = p21
```

Answer (score 1):

You can now do this within `ggpairs` by mapping an aesthetic to a particular plot

```
ggpairs(data=data.frame(a, b, point.colors), 
        columns=c("a", "b"), 
        lower = list(continuous = "points", mapping=aes(color=point.colors)))
```

Note, that in this case you do not need to add `point.colors` to your dataframe as the `aes` call will find it in the global environment (and so then you could also omit the `columns=` statement). However, it feels a bit more robust to include it.

PS Given that you were unable to use the functionality of `p[2,1] = p21` given in bouncys' answer, you may need to update your version of `GGally`.